# How to update value instead of restarting the app

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, onesignal

I have this piece of code in my iOS app inside WebViewController.swift:

```
var pushIDOneSignal = userID
if pushIDOneSignal == nil
{
    // do nothing
}
else
{
    webviewurl += pushIDOneSignal! //Add PushID token to the URL
}
```

I'm using `pushIDOneSignal` to get the playerid for the user. The problem is when the user opens the app the first time, we get a nil value; because has to accept permission notifications first.

Somehow I managed to create a way to get the playerid, but it only works if the user accepts the notifications and then, closes the app, and opens again.

How can I make the app try to read this again: `if pushIDOneSignal == nil` after the user has accepted notifications? Then that time, will get the else condition and then we will get the playerid.

Edit:

I have idea-

```
if pushIDOneSignal == nil
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                webviewurl += pushIDOneSignal! //Add PushID token to the URL
            }
```

How i can make keeps looping when value is nil? Thanks.

Comment: Or is there any way to make the WebViewController.swift reload entire? Or reload at single line?

Thanks.

Comment: WOW.... I don't think you are in right path... have tried to read the OneSignal docs ? Thought about using the push notification authorization callback ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GIJOW im not developer, so im doing what i can. I tried to search on their documentation but most of the things i don't understand how to use them properly...